# Why rm command unrecognized w flag in AIX?

Tags: bash, rm, aix

I have a bash script that retain the last 5 copies in AIX like this:

```
rm `ls -lt /path/the_file_* | tail -n +6`
```

But I get this error:

```
rm: Not a recognized flag: w
```

**UPDATE**

The `ls` command return this:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 user   group1           14 Mar 11 09:54 the_file_20130311.bz2
```

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 4):

What you say is essentially

```
rm -rw-r--r-- 1 user group1 14 Mar 11 09:54 the_file_20130311.bz2
```

In other words. Remove recursively files named:

```
1
user
group1
14
Mar
...
```

If there was a `-w` flag to rm and the other oddities in `-rw-r--r--`

A better option could be to use `ls -t`. Do not worry about it not being on separate lines as `ls` detect whether it's output is to a tty or not.

Demonstrated by e.g.:

```
ls -t | cat
```

But then another problem arises, and that is the fact you are not in the correct directory. So what you say is actually remove files in current directory which is named the same as the 6 last in `/path/`.

So ensure you are in correct path first, or, another option if you can install the GNU `find` on your system would be something in the direction of:

```
find /path/to/files -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'the_file_*' -printf '%T@ %p\n' |
  sort -nr | head -n6 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

Note that you need the full path to get correct listing.

Then; if that looks OK add it to a `rm` routine.

Answer (score 1):

What does the `ls ...` command return? Remember that that command is run, and the output is given to `rm` as arguments. Nothing makes the output be "file names". If there really should be a `-w` file in there, perhaps `--` ends flags on AIX, and it should be `rm -- ...`

**Update:**

Oh, brain slip. The `ls -l` will give not only the file names, but also permissions, e.g. `-rw...`, and (as explained above) `rm` takes this as flags. You should do:

```
rm `ls -t /path/the_file_* | tail -n +6`
```

And some commands (it's a GNU convention many others have picked up) take `--` meaning "flags end here". So to delete a file called `-rf` you can do `rm -- -rf`, an in general to not pick up spurious flags, you can say `cmd -flags -x -y -- anything goes here`.

Comment: I have new update on what `ls` is return in my question. I'm not really sure what is `--` command? Any sample of usage?

Comment: `--` is simply an argument that many commands interpret as a signal to stop processing options, so that any further arguments that begin with `-` are treated as regular arguments, not options.

Comment: @vonbrand I don't think `--` originated with GNU, and it's mandated by POSIX (with a few exceptions such as `echo` for historical reasons).